# Buffer to image node js

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a server/client communication in node js.
Every second, the server send an image (taking by a camera) to the client.

The message structure contains among other things:

- BufferX : the width of the image
- BufferY : the height of the image
- BufferImage  : Bytes array containing pixel

The problem is: I would like to convert this buffer to an image and save it.

At first I try this:

```
let array = new Uint8Array(BufferImage  );
fs.writeFileSync("data.png",array)
```

But the image isn't readable because the buffer only contains raw pixels data.

I've copy past the buffer to a python script, convert to a numpy array and reshape it. The image is correct so I'm sure that the ImageBuffer contains the correct value.

So is it possible to convert a raw pixel buffer to an image ?

Comment: Have you tried [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp)?

Comment: I did not know this module, I will take a look. Thank you

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```js
let array = new Uint8Array(BufferImage);
fs.writeFileSync("data.png", Buffer.from(array).toString('base64'))
```

Comment: Yes I've tried something similar but it's doesn't work. I supposed that the writeFileSync function can not reshape the buffer with the good dimensions. The width and the height of the image isn't stored in the image BufferImage, it only contains raw pixels value